# Passing an array of objects in a hidden input to JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I've found a number of articles with the same issue, but I'm not sure why those solutions aren't working for me.  I have a multidimensional array that has pairs of project and tag key/value pairs. I define the array in the controller like this:

```
foreach ($data['toolsProjects'] as $tool) {
  foreach ($tool->tags as $tag) {
     $tag_filter_list[]=array($tool->uid=>$tag->fldTag);
  }
}
```

When I console.log the array on the page it looks like this:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {project28: 'deer browse'}
1: {project28: 'regeneration'}
2: {project29: 'recreation'}
3: {project11: 'forest health'}
4: {tool20: 'forest health'}
5: {tool20: 'regeneration'}
```

When I put it into a hidden input, I use json_encode like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tag_filter_list" value="<?php echo json_encode($tag_filter_list) ?>" />
```

Then, when I try to use it with JQuery, I am getting an error about the formatting of the JSON.

```
var tag_filter_list=JSON.parse($('#tag_filter_list').val());
```

I get the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse ()

When I console typeof $('#tag_filter_list') it says string, but I guess it's not in the correct format?  But I thought json_encode would take care of that?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: so what is `console.log($('#tag_filter_list').val());` When you inspect the element in the developer console, what does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: for your `value=""` I would use single quotes instead of double so `<input type="hidden" id="tag_filter_list" value='<?php echo json_encode($tag_filter_list) ?>' />` Json formatting includes double quotes

Comment: why are you not just outputting the JavaScript to the page? Seems odd to be putting it into an input.

Comment: Right, just use `var tag_filter_list = <?php echo json_encode($tag_filter_list); ?>;`

Comment: @imvain2 That's better, but it won't work correctly if there are any single quotes in the array.

Comment: @barmar, @epaascarello my Javascript is outside of the page, in an attached file.  So not accessible using `var tag_filter_list`. `console.log(($('#tag_filter_list').val());` shows just square then curly bracket `[{`

Comment: You should call `htmlspecialchars()` in addition to `json_encode()`: `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($tag_filter_list), , ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML5); ?>"`

Comment: @Barmar adding  htmlspecialchars worked!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode()` outputs something like `{"key":"value"}`, and if you put that straight into the html markup, it will render like this:

```
<input value="{"key":"value"}">
```

So now if you try to read the value of the input it's just `{` (the rest of it is no longer part of the value). Thus the first character is valid, but the second character (undefined) is not (minimum valid json is `{}`)

The work around I use for this is to wrap it in [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), so

```
<?php echo urlencode(json_encode(...)); ?>
```

this will replace the double quotes and other markup breaking characters with their escaped html values

```
<input value="%7B%22key%22%3A%22value%22%7D">
```

then when you go to parse it client side just make sure you wrap it in
[decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well friend, I believe that the error in this case is the use of single quotes and double quotes. Try:

leave it like this:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {project28: "deer browse"}
...
```

rather than:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {project28: 'deer browse'}
```

Another thing, remember that the input must receive a string, but in your case, an object is being passed, so you need to access the key, as in the first index of this array, like:

```
<?php echo $tag_filter_list[0]->project28; ?>
```

Good luck!